# Difference Internal Testing vs License Testing in Google Play Console for Google Assistant Integration with Android App

Tags: android, android-studio, app-actions, google-assistant

I have done a PoC on integrating Google Assistant with Android App and I could able to do it successfully. So now I need to deploy it and wants others to use it for internal purpose. Ongoing through google documentation, it says we can add users (QA) as a Licensed Testers from the google play console. But we need to log in with the tester's email Id from Android Studio and keep updating the preview every 6 hours. So my question is can we put the app in internal testing and publish it and create an internal tester list and keep it open only for them. Does avoid us to sign in to Android Studio and keep updating the preview every 6 hours?

Comment: I imagine the easiest thing to do is try and see if it works. App Actions test tool previews are meant for development testing purposes only (so you don't have to upload a new APK every time you want to see if your actions.xml is working correctly).

Comment: @DougStevenson Is there any official documentation from Google on this? So that I can share with my stakeholders and convince them to publish the app in the play store under Internal Testing.